# Am I using too many training data in GEE?

Tags: classification, google-earth-engine

I am running a classification script in GEE and I have about 2100 training data since my AOI is a region in Italy and have many classes. I receive the following error while I try save my script:

> Script error File too large (larger than 512KB).

I tried cancelling some of the training data and it saves. I thought there is no limit in GEE to choose training points. How can I know what is the limit so I adjust my training points or if there is a way to save the script without deleting any points.
[Here is the link to my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/84875d74a1b380dbed12cee047758bed?accept_repo=users%2Fessepratico%2FPratico_et_al_RemoteSensing_2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Earth Engine Code Editor “drawing tools” are a convenient, but not very scalable, way to create geometry. The error you're getting is because “under the covers” they actually create additional code that is part of your script file. Not only is this fairly verbose (hence the error you received), it's not very efficient to run, either.

In order to use large training data sets, you will need to create your point data in another tool and upload it (using CSV or SHP files) to become one or more Earth Engine “table” assets, and use those from your script.

Comment: thanks. I will try creating this option for sure.